# Getting error C2039 on vista32bit while the same code works correctly on XP

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, windows-vista

I'm using visual studio 2005. I executed my code in XP windows and it worked correctly, but when I want to do the same in vista32 it starts to say these errors which seems strange. I've searched a lot and found this a common problem but I couldn't find any clear and useful solution. If some body helps I would appreciate it very much.

> Error  1   error C2039: '_strtoi64' : is not a member of '`global namespace''  c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xlocnum   469
>
> Error  2   error C3861: '_strtoi64': identifier not found  c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xlocnum   469
>
> Error  3   error C2039: '_strtoi64' : is not a member of '`global namespace''  c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xlocnum   469
>
> Error  4   error C3861: '_strtoi64': identifier not found  c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xlocnum   469
>
> Error  5   error C2039: '_strtoi64' : is not a member of '`global namespace''  c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xlocnum   469
>
> Error  6   error C3861: '_strtoi64': identifier not found  c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xlocnum   469
>
> Error  41  error C2039: '_strtoi64' : is not a member of '`global namespace''  c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xlocnum   469
>
> Error  42  error C3861: '_strtoi64': identifier not found  c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xlocnum   469

Comment: You can't get compile errors by executing your code on a different computer.  What are you really doing?

Comment: THese are all compile-time errors.  Are they visual studio 2005 on both machines that you're compiling on?

Comment: yeah both of them are vs 2005, i even executed it on another pc with the same windows(vista) and same VS, and again worked properly.i dont know whats wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just uninstall and again reinstall the visual 2005 and surprisingly it worked, tnx for all your advices.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Check Include section in Visual Studio dependency and project dependency. Maybe you include some directory with std headers from old SDK. Standard directories should be on the top of the list.

Comment: Those are compile errors, so not related to wrong version of a runtime library.  OTOH installing Visual Studio service packs might help.

Answer (score -1):

Somebody is referencing the function strtoi64( ), which converts a C-string to a 64-bit integer. But you are running on a 32-bit system so there is no such function. First, I would look into the offending file, which is somewhere in or around

```
c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 8\vc\include\xlocnum
```

(whatever that is) at line 469 to see what that guy is trying to do.

It seems likely to me that when VS was installed onto the Vista machine, someone somehow enabled 64-bit compilation, so imo you will probably have to go through the VC configs to make sure they are all 32-bit settings.

Comment: 64-bit compilation has nothing to do with 64-bit datatypes.  I can have a 64-bit integer on a 32-bit box.  I can have arbitrary precision datatypes regardless of architecture.

Comment: @Joe -- Right you are. Thanks!